# How to fix error trying to migrate manage.py

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am a beginner when it comes to python so i watch tutorials regulary. The Django framework tutorial i'm watching right now eventually had a step where i had to run the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

i got the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer 
is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

i know that there are other answers to this error but none work for me.

does anybody have a fix?

Comment: You want to use virtualenv just to avoid the very kind of errors.

Comment: As the error says, you need to install mysqlclient 1.3.13 or later. Saying that none of the other answers helped isn't enough information for us to help you. What answers did you try, and what happened? What operating system, python version and Django version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install pymysql for Django like this.

```
pip install pymysql
```

or (if you python3)

```
pip3 install pymysql --upgrade
```

If you are in venv, first of all you must have to activate that.

Comment: This is what i get when i enter `pip install pymysql --upgrade`

`(py1) C:\Projects\djangoproject>pip3 install pymysql --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: pymysql in c:\users\denze\envs\py1\lib\site-packages (0.9.3)`

It says it's already up to date while its on 0.9.3. Also, the virtual env is already activated i think (It's called py1).

Comment: Django doesn’t officially support pymysql so I suggest you use mysqlclient unless you have a good reason to use pymysql. After activating a virtual environment, just use `python` and `pip` instead of `python3` and `pip3`.

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade `mysqlclient` for Django. So do this:

```
pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

if you have virtual environment, first of all you must activate that. Then run this  line of code. It is recommended to use venv and then install your packages into that for better management of your project.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are telling you what to install, to help avoid these kinds of errors in future you should use virtual envs.

Virtualenv will isolate your Python/Django setup on a per-project basis. This means that any changes you make to one project won't affect any others you're also developing.

```
$ mkdir yourdirname
$ cd yourdirname
```

Then you can use

```
$ python3 -m venv whateveryouwannanameyourvenv
```

And finally:

```
C:\Users\Name\yourdirname> myvenv\Scripts\activate
```

From there you can run `pip install mysql` and you can have different environments for each project.